# How many bottles of perfume can I bring in to India when flying back from Dubai?

Tags: india, regulations, gifts

I have bought six bottles of perfume of 100ml each, priced at 700-800 INR. I plan to use these bottles as a gift. How many bottles of perfume can I bring back to India when flying back from Dubai?.

I couldn't find any clarification on the government websites regarding this. I don't want to carry anything beyond the limits.

Answer (score 6):

Perfumes are not listed as a [regulated item](http://customsmumbaiairport.gov.in/Hindi/Content.aspx?LinkID=64), hence you should not have issues with perfumes - as long as the value is less that what is allowed; which is 35,000 INR (if your stay outside of India as more than 3 days) or 15,000 INR if less than 3 days.